# why is this coming back true and not false?

Tags: if-statement, equals

For the life of me I have no idea why this code is coming back true when the variables I am using are not the same.

```
 deleteComment(comment){
      console.log(this.user.id)
      console.log(this.$route.params.id) 
        if('this.user.id', '==', 'this.$route.params.id'){
              db.collection("comments").doc(comment.id).delete();
              console.log("Document successfully deleted!")
            } else {
              console.log('no can do')
            }
         }
       }
   }
```

say this.user.id = a and this.$route.params.id = b.

I run this code console.log has the values correct with each log. But then this still deletes the doc, when it should not.

From my understanding if(a == b) is not true then it should drop down to the else portion of code? Using Vue

Comment: Check your if statement, the syntax is just wrong. Remove the ' and the ,

Comment: My question would be why you think this should work. I've never seen an `if` that works like that. What you are telling it is to evaluate 3 expressions, discard the first 2, and test the last. Since the last is a non-empty string, it's true-ish, so you do the affirmative case. I really doubt you can delete _but_ get the `no can do` output. Show full code, example inputs, desired output, and current output.

Answer (score 0):

Asking if any string with a length is truthy, will always result in `true`

I read this as saying

```
if (true, true, true) {
   // Something will always happen
} else { // This will never run }
```

Did you mean

```
if (this.user.id === this.$route.params.id) {
   // Something will sometimes happen
}
```